# How to handle null from a Json which importing in pytest

Tags: json, null, pytest

I have a Json object stored in a data.py file

```
data_1 = {"company" = "XYZ", "Name" : null, "Number"  = null}
```

I have another file in which I have written a pytest

```
import pytest

def test_1():
    input_ = X
    result = func_1(input_)
    from .data import data_1
    output = data_1
    assert result == output
```

func_1 after taking input returns same output as data_1 but with None instead of null.
After running the pytest it is showing  error in 'from .data import data_1' line as

```
NameError : name 'null' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `data.py` file is not valid python code, which raises the error. null is not known to python, therefore python thinks it's a variable name, but finds it is not defined => Error. You can test this by trying to print something that is not defined. It gives the same error:

```
print(variable_which_was_never_defined)
# Output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'variable_which_was_never_defined' is not defined
```

Although, python dictionaries look a lot like json, they are not json objects.

What I usually do in order to handle json in tests is to declare the json as a string like so:

```
data_1 = """{"company": "XYZ", "Name": null, "Number": null}"""
```

Then you can use the json package to parse it to a dictionary and compare the dicts:

```
import pytest
import json

def test_1():
    input_ = X
    result = func_1(input_)
    from .data import data_1
    output = json.loads(data_1)
    assert result == output
```

Or if `func_1` returns a json string, you can directly compare the strings (note than you can use your code as is and just need to fix the `data.py` file:

```
import pytest

def test_1():
    input_ = X
    result = func_1(input_)
    from .data import data_1
    output = data_1
    assert result == output
```